# How to control height of a div to scale in large screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have layout with many tiles in it. To make sure the height scales properly in all devices. I used percentage and min-height but alignment tends to break in large screens due to constant spacing between tiles. Then I tried using padding within elements to align. But a table in it needs height to be set to prevent overflow. What is the best way to control height of the tiles.

Comment: are you familiar with viewport heights?

Comment: height: 100vh; means the height is 100% height of the screen. so its almost like a percentage but sometimes its better to use vh instead of percentage for the height property

Comment: I agree but does it scales properly if user resizes window vertically

Comment: yes it does. try it out and let me know what happens